# RegEx pattern separator to split columns doesn't work

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, separator

I'm trying to get my regex pattern to work on a column I want to split with the `separator()` function from the `tidyr` package. However I can't figure out why my pattern isn't working.

Here's my input dataframe:
The column `gemeente` means 'municipality' in english and `partijen` means 'political parties'.

```
      gemeente                                                      partijen
1        Asten                 CDA 1 , Algemeen Belang 1 en Leefbaar Asten 1
2         Beek                                              BBB-NDB 2, CDA 2
3    Coevorden                                     PvdA 1, CDA 1 en Lokaal 1
4       Ermelo Progressief Ermelo 1, BurgerBelangen Ermelo 1, SGP 1 en VVD 1
5 Heeze-Leende                Lokaal  Heeze-Leende 1, CDA 1, D66 1 en PvdA 1
6        Hulst   Algemeen Belang Groot Hulst 1,5, CDA 1, PvdA 0,7 en VVD 0,8
7    Roerdalen          RoerstreekLokaal! 1, CDA 1 en Democraten Roerdalen 1
8         Uden    Jong Uden 1, CDA 1 , Gewoon Uden 1 en VVD-Leefbaar Uden 1
```

Everything what's before or in between a number is a local party in the Netherlands. I want get every every party in its own column then transpose to tidy my data frame. The word `en` means 'and' in Dutch so we can remove that one as well.

here's a `dput()` output of that same data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(gemeente = c("Asten", "Beek", "Coevorden", "Ermelo", 
"Heeze-Leende", "Hulst", "Roerdalen", "Uden"), partijen = c("CDA 1 , Algemeen Belang 1 en Leefbaar Asten 1", 
"BBB-NDB 2, CDA 2", "PvdA 1, CDA 1 en Lokaal 1", "Progressief Ermelo 1, BurgerBelangen Ermelo 1, SGP 1 en VVD 1", 
"Lokaal  Heeze-Leende 1, CDA 1, D66 1 en PvdA 1", "Algemeen Belang Groot Hulst 1,5, CDA 1, PvdA 0,7 en VVD 0,8", 
"RoerstreekLokaal! 1, CDA 1 en Democraten Roerdalen 1", "Jong Uden 1, CDA 1 , Gewoon Uden 1 en VVD-Leefbaar Uden 1 "
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("gemeente", "partijen"))
```

...below my code that is almost but not fully working.
First I get rid of the numbers (I don't use space or comma because there's a party that's called `D66`) then I `separate` into multiple columns with two separators `sep = ", |,| , | en "`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(partijen = gsub(" [0-9]|\\,[0-9]", "", partijen)) %>%
  separate(partijen, 
           into = c("partij_1", "partij_2", "partij_3", "partij_4"),
           sep = ", |,| , | en ")
```

My output running is the following:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  gemeente     partij_1                    partij_2                          partij_3                          partij_4
  <chr>        <chr>                       <chr>                             <chr>                             <chr>   
1 Asten        CDA                         Algemeen Belang en Leefbaar Asten NA                                NA      
2 Beek         BBB-NDB                     CDA                               NA                                NA      
3 Coevorden    PvdA                        CDA                               Lokaal                            NA      
4 Ermelo       Progressief Ermelo          BurgerBelangen Ermelo             SGP en VVD                        NA      
5 Heeze-Leende Lokaal  Heeze-Leende        CDA                               D66                               PvdA    
6 Hulst        Algemeen Belang Groot Hulst CDA                               PvdA                              VVD     
7 Roerdalen    RoerstreekLokaal!           CDA en Democraten Roerdalen       NA                                NA      
8 Uden         Jong Uden                   CDA                               Gewoon Uden en VVD-Leefbaar Uden  NA   
Warning message:
Expected 4 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 6 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8].
```

You see my problem?

I don't get why the `sep = ", |,| , | en "` doesn't work for the `en` between two parties:

- `"Algemeen Belang en Leefbaar Asten"`
- `"SGP en VVD"`
- `CDA en Democraten Roerdalen"`
- etc....

Comment: Seems to work for me, but I'm in the US and based on the language here I suspect you're not? Could it be a locale issue? Or maybe some hidden characters in your version of the data?

Comment: I'm in the Netherlands, Europe. How do I figure out if there's hidden data?

Comment: Also worth checking package versions, I'm also seeing it work using the current version of `tidyr` 0.8.0. What's your version?

Comment: hmm I've got the same version: `tidyr_0.8.0`. Maybe sharing my session info helps?

Comment: Maybe. Also, please verify that, in a fresh R session, your example *doesn't* work for you. Use the `dput` data (which doesn't have any hidden characters) and the code from the question and verify the problem.

Comment: When I use the pattern `"[[:space:]]en[[:space:]]"` instead of `" en "` it works!

Answer (score 1):

When I use this pattern `"[[:space:]]en[[:space:]]"` instead of `" en "` in the `sep =` argument of the `separator` function it splits correctly.

So the code that works (for me) is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(partijen = gsub(" [0-9]|\\,[0-9]", "", partijen)) %>%
  separate(partijen, 
           into = c("partij_1", "partij_2", "partij_3", "partij_4"),
           sep = ", |,| , |[[:space:]]en[[:space:]]")
```